# Make environment names language dependant

Tags: languages

I am writing a document in Italian and there are a number of things i don't know how to get.
Most importantly, when I use a `\begin{example}` environment, the resulting text shows *Example*, while I'd like the Italian word for 'Example'.

Additionally, when making references to items in a list, cleveref calls them *Item*'s, and in this case I would like the Italian word for it.

Is there a way to do this naming automatically? I tried `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` but that didn't work.

Comment: Adding `\crefname{example}{esempio}{esempi}` should help. I don't know of a good Italian substitute for “item”, so I'd simply omit it.

Comment: I was hoping someone had already done the work and i'd only have to import a package / set some conditions ...  thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: @Squera: That's what everyone want's. Life is not always that easy. :-|

Comment: @Squera Well, If I do `\newtheorem{example}{Esempio}`, with `\cref` I get "esempio`.